# Set datagrid cell to 0 if another cell is greater than 0

Tags: c#, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I know my title is not clear but here's my problem:
I have 1 datagrid where it has 2 columns. Percentage and Abs Amt.
Now, if Percentage > 0, Abs Amt should be zero and vice versa.

I tried to do it using DataTriggers but I'm lost and scrapped everything...

Here's my code:

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Percentage"
                              CellTemplate="{StaticResource local.Percentage}" />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Absolute Amt"
                              CellTemplate="{StaticResource local.AbsAmt}" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>


<DataTemplate x:Key="local.Percentage">
    <Grid>
        <Border Height="30"
                Margin="-2"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBox  x:Name="percentage" 
                      Text="{Binding value-binded-to-VM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Margin="0,0,2,4"
                      Height="Auto"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>


<DataTemplate x:Key="local.AbsAmt">
    <Grid>
        <Border Height="30"
                Margin="-2"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBox  x:Name="abscharge" 
                      Text="{Binding value-binded-to-VM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Margin="0,0,2,4"
                      Height="Auto"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it possible to control a cell from another cell? Or should I just do the validation on VM before saving...?

TIA!

Comment: Sounds to me like this is entirely related to data so it's best to just add a check in your setters if the value is 0 and then set the value of the other property to 0. When setting the dependent property, don't use the setter to avoid a cyclical reference, instead, change the variable behind the property directly and raise the property changed notification to update the grid view.

Comment: That was actually my last resort. Im planning to control them inside their property in my VM. I was hoping to do it inside xaml but I guess I can't.. Or maybe doing it inside VM is the proper way? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Like I said, this is a data constraint. The whole idea of MVVM is to separate data model from the view, so you should conform to that.